# Vimeo video in Landscape Mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In one app i am displaying videos from Vimeo and Youtube. All videos should be open in Landscape Mode by default. Whole App is on Portrait orientation based only. Youtube Video is opening in Landscape mode automatically and also supporting orientation without any effort which i want but problem is with Vimeo Video. Vimeo Video is not playing in Landscape Mode and also not supporting orientation. I m in big trouble, if any one know please help me.
for Youtube i have loaded following Html String:

```
 NSString *embedHTML =  @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
return html;
```

And for Vimeo i have written following Html String:

```
@"<iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@?title=0&autoplay=0&portrait=0&color=333&api=1&player_id=vimeoplayer\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>"
```